# Database Design Help: Multiple form fields with each field having properties

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

So I am working on a project that has form fields (like name, email, etc) and each of those fields have properties (isPrivate, hasPriority)

Typically with a form handling assigned to users I'd do something like:

```
Table: Values 
 Columns:  ID - USERID - NAME - EMAIL - PHONE - Field4 ... Field30
```

where each row represents a user and their full form entries. I've built up on this schema but now I need settings/properties for each form field for each user. I.e user 50's email is private. What would be the best way to go about this? Currently I'm thinking that I could do something like:

```
Table: Values 
 Columns:  ID - USERID - NAME - EMAIL - PHONE - Field4 ... Field30
Table: isPrivate 
 Columns:  ID - USERID - NAME - EMAIL - PHONE - Field4 ... Field30
Table: hasPriority 
 Columns:  ID - USERID - NAME - EMAIL - PHONE - Field4 ... Field30
```

However, I wonder if that is a good idea, as it's not really normalized and there's not a good way for me to say add more properties if I would ever need them in the future (I would have to create a new table every time).

Anyone have any good solutions for a schema like this? I'd be down to learn/switch over to a document based database if it's necessary...

Comment: Two tables.... one with form values and one with form options. Referenced by user ID.

Comment: Store the form options as arrays in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

You should spin off those for, fields that reference those values into separate tables and reference them with ids.

Answer (score 0):

try this schema:

table: field

columns: id, name, label, description, input_type, input_value, status

table: answer

columns: id, userid, field_id, answer, status

now on the 2 tables above here is the definition:

The **field** table will have a list of all the fields that the users would able to fillup their answers will be stored on a separate table which is the **answer** on the status it depends on you how you would signify each value for example:
1 = private
2 = haspriority
...
and so on.